# How to set up a very secure file server for home backup that is not available to the internet?

Tags: server, backup

I am trying to setup a home backup machine running ubuntu. I want to be able to rsync from other linux machines and possibly from windows 7 (the windows part is not essential). 
I have read lots of tutorials about setting up with internet access but my aim is to have maximum security and not be able to access this machine from the internet.

Comment: Just put the files in your home folder, and make sure your home folder is encrypted at installation.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first you should be behind a router and if your router is properly configured you can not reach the server from outside ("the internet").

Otherwise, use your firewall. UFW is an easy to use front end to iptables

```
sudo ufw default deny
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.0.0/24
```

change "192.168.0.0/24" you your netmask.

See

http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/firewall-ubuntu-servers/

http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/iptables

Also look at securing your server (IMO you should rsync over ssh)

http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/SSH_security